# React Native: Requiring Unknow Module

Tags: react-native

I just started with react-native and was building this sample application:

xcode version: 6.2
OS : OS X 10.9.5
node version: 0.10.28

**index.ios.js**

```
var React = require('react-native');
var Main = require('./App/Components/Main');


var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  NavigatorIOS,
  View,
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#111111'
  },
});

class githubNotetaker extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
      style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Github NoteTaker',
          component: Main
        }} />
    );
  }
};


AppRegistry.registerComponent('githubNotetaker', () => githubNotetaker);
```

**Main.js**

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 30,
    marginTop: 65,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC'
  },
  title: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  searchInput: {
    height: 50,
    padding: 4,
    marginRight: 5,
    fontSize: 23,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 8,
    color: 'white'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#111',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 45,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderColor: 'white',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
});

class Main extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <Text> Testing the Router </Text>
      </View>
      )
  }
};

module.exports = Main;
```

**Error**

[image: Error I am getting in simulator]

I getting clueless why it is not able to location Main.js module.

Comment: It seems that the Main path is wrong. I have encountered this error when the path was miswritten

Comment: @nicopasso is correct. Re-check the path and make sure it is correct and nothing is misspelt in your "var Main = require('./App/Components/Main');" call. You can also maybe try restarting or rebuilding the app.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. I have verified that nothing is misspelt - has anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

The issue was little different.

In my file index.io.js I named my class as githubNotetaker while the project directory name was githubNoteTaker. I changed my class name to githubNoteTaker.

One more thing to add, also my tutorial didn't mention, I had to start npm serve using command npm start. I did that and application worked like a charm